# Spring MVC JSP - Include another JSP that has Dynamic Data

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have a Spring controller that calls a JSP (**searchForm**).  I also need to have an included JSP from within the **searchForm**.  However the included JSP is not static - its data comes from a database call.  I know I can include a JSP within another JSP, similar to below, but how can I trigger a controller to populate the **ArrayList** that **include.jsp** displays?

Am I not going about this the correct way?  The **include.jsp** will be used on more than one page, so I want to have it as an include.

```
<%@ include file="/WEB-INF/views/include.jsp" %>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would simply call a method from the main controller, in order to populate the model with the data needed by the included JSP. And I would call this same method from every other controller dispatching to a page including the same JSP.

Comment: I will happily listen to someone who asked 3 questions, and answered 6,075  :)  Thank you.